# Flink 1.9.0 - State deserialization fails after changing the state object

Tags: java, serialization, apache-flink, kryo

After changing the state object, our state fails to load. (not surprising)

Our state object looks something like this:

```java
public class StateHolder {
    private Set<Object1> objects1 = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<Object2> objects2 = new HashSet<>();
    // 4 more sets of objects, Object3 to Object6 let's call them that
    // no args constructor, and getters and setters
...
}
```

And it is used like this:

```
ValueStateDescriptor<StateHolder> aggregateValueStateDescriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<>(
                getDescriptorNamePrefix(STATE_PREFIX, STATE_NAME_COMMAND_AGGREGATE, DATE_OF_STATE_CREATION),
                TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<StateHolder>() {
                })
        );
        commandAggregateState = getRuntimeContext().getState(aggregateValueStateDescriptor);
```

Recently, we added the field to `Object3`. We set the default value to it. It is a string and it's defined as : `private String newField = "";`

After doing so we are getting the following exception:

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 104
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:119)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:641)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:752)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.deserialize(KryoSerializer.java:346)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.PojoSerializer.deserialize(PojoSerializer.java:411)
    at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBValueState.value(RocksDBValueState.java:90)
```

Obviously, our Sets are being deserialized using KryoSerializer and I guess that was something to be expected. Presumably not ideal though.

What I am failing to understand is why exactly is this failing and how to tackle this issue? So we added field to `Object3` class, but deserialization fails on `objects5` field (`Set<Object5>`). Could new field cause buffer to shift unexpectedly so that Registration ID was read from wrong position?

Our POJO conforms to all the rules listed in documentation (Maybe this might not be relevant since it's Kryo deserialization that fails):

```
* The class is public and standalone (no non-static inner class)
* The class has a public no-argument constructor
* All non-static, non-transient fields in the class (and all superclasses) are either public (and non-final) or have a public getter- and a setter- method that follows the Java beans naming conventions for getters and setters.
```

By googling the exception, there were some suggestions like implementing custom Serializer.
Would you agree that this is the right approach to take? If so, by googling, I only found out how to do custom Avro and Protobuff serializers, neither of which we are using to preserve state. Seemingly, our data is serialized with PojoSerializer which uses different KryoSerializers for deserializing our Sets, and one of them is obviously failing. Should we create new custom `PojoSerializer` with a custom `KryoSerializer` for this failing field, and if so, how is that custom `KryoSerializer` supposed to look like? Should we have hard coded registration id which conforms to `java.util.Set`?

Thank you for reading all this, and I apologize if this is the duplicate question. I couldn't find one similiar enough to this one.

**UPDATE**

So, after suggestion to move new field initialization to default value to NoArgsConstructor, our original exception is just being wrapped.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while getting state
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultKeyedStateStore.getState(DefaultKeyedStateStore.java:62)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamingRuntimeContext.getState(StreamingRuntimeContext.java:144)
at fake.package.pipeline.handler.codebook.function.CommandHandlerCodeBookFunction.initializeState(CommandHandlerCodeBookFunction.java:88)
at fake.package.pipeline.handler.Handler.open(Handler.java:104)
at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:102)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.co.KeyedCoProcessOperator.open(KeyedCoProcessOperator.java:62)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.openAllOperators(StreamTask.java:532)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:396)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:705)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:530)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.StateMigrationException: Error while trying to migrate RocksDB state.
at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.AbstractRocksDBState.migrateSerializedValue(AbstractRocksDBState.java:213)
at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.migrateStateValues(RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.java:603)
at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.updateRestoredStateMetaInfo(RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.java:532)
at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.tryRegisterKvStateInformation(RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.java:482)
at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.createInternalState(RocksDBKeyedStateBackend.java:643)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.KeyedStateFactory.createInternalState(KeyedStateFactory.java:47)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.ttl.TtlStateFactory.createStateAndWrapWithTtlIfEnabled(TtlStateFactory.java:72)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.AbstractKeyedStateBackend.getOrCreateKeyedState(AbstractKeyedStateBackend.java:279)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.AbstractKeyedStateBackend.getPartitionedState(AbstractKeyedStateBackend.java:328)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultKeyedStateStore.getPartitionedState(DefaultKeyedStateStore.java:124)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultKeyedStateStore.getState(DefaultKeyedStateStore.java:60)
... 11 more
Caused by: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 104
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:119)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:641)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:752)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.kryo.KryoSerializer.deserialize(KryoSerializer.java:346)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.runtime.PojoSerializer.deserialize(PojoSerializer.java:411)
at org.apache.flink.contrib.streaming.state.AbstractRocksDBState.migrateSerializedValue(AbstractRocksDBState.java:210)
... 21 more
```

Comment: Im trying to simulate it on my local environment without success, can you post your code maybe? if not, when does this error occures? on the start of the program or when data is arriving? If you remove the default value(and add this in the NoArgsConstractor) it works? (I mean Initialize the newField in the NoArgsConstractor).
Also, is that error occures when running local or only at production?

Comment: @ShemTov Unfortunately, I cannot share the exact code with you. We tried this on our test environment (openshift) and we had populated state in RocksDB. When we added the field as described, flink started failing with the mentioned exception as it couldn't deserialize state anymore, when flink is trying to migrate state. After moving initializations to no args constructor, we are having the somewhat same but different exception than before, will be edited in my original post cuz it's too long for comments.

Comment: I try dig into flink and kyro code with the stacktrace you have been attached, it is little bit hard without debugging, but can u try adding serial version uid of 1 to each of your objects? you doing it by adding this line to class: "private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;". Please update.